# Visual Studio installer - how restore missed components

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019

I'm downloading VS 2019 community with help of:

```
vs_community.exe --layout g:\cat\e-install\install\Dev\ide-editors-platforms\VS\vs2019-all-layout_en_US\ --lang en-US
```

During the doanload disk `g` was unavailable for few seconds, i saw messages kind of:

`Error: Finished with errors. Error: Can't find path "g:\cat\vs2019-all-layout_en_US_16_11\Microsoft.VisualC.14.25.MFC.Redist.X64,version=14.25.28508".`

How can i re-run downloading, verify missed packages, and download only missed packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I re-run downloading, verify missed packages, and download only missed packages?

**Yes**, you can just use `--fix` command to verify and fix(fix the missing packages).

The official document: [Layout command and command-line parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#layout-command-and-command-line-parameters) mentioned

> `--fix`  => Verify the contents of a layout. If any files are corrupt or missing, they’re redownloaded. Internet access is required to fix a layout.

And the command should be like this:

```
vs_community.exe --layout g:\XXXX\XXXX\... --fix
```

[image]